# Meu aplicativo Android Studio não tem 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, sdk

Sou novo no Android studio.
Criei um aplicativo com uma implementação de firebase para fazer login nele. Porém ao sincronizar com firebase comeca uma serie de erros.
**Primeiro**, que ao adcionar sdk de autenticação firebase, ele simplesmente não funciona.
[Erro Sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3aKX.png)
**Segundo**. Quando vou no servidor firebase pelo navegador, ele não conecta e me leva á uma pagina localhost.
[Erro conectar ao app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzhnM.png)
[Erro conectar ao app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0WwS.png)
**Terceiro**. Vi tutoriais para resolver esse problema. Percebi que em todos eles tinham pelo menos as dependências no gradle a seguir:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

O meu gradle não tinha nenhuma dessas:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.codeek.workoutapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codeek.workoutapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

Acho que posso ter errado na instalação do Android Studio. Teria como resolver isso sem reinstalar o android studio?

Comment: Tentei conectar ao firebase seguindo o seguinte tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1tf_ByFATo&t=1145s

Comment: Esse tutorial é bem antigo (2019). Muita coisa mudou de lá para cá. Sugiro que siga a documentação oficial do Firebase que costuma estar mais atualizada: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start?hl=pt-br